# \nocite not working for elsearticle document class

Tags: citing, elsarticle

The `\nocite` command doesn't seem to work in an `elsarticle` document class. Note that upon downloading Elsarticle, it's bundled with customized `bst` files for different citation styles. I have tried the `bst` files for APA, Vancouver and Harvard. And none of them seem to allow `\nocite.`

There is no error message, the final pdf comes out alright, except that it omits the references included in the `\nocite` from the bibliography list.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black, citecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\modulolinenumbers[5]

\journal{Journal of XXX}

%%% Bibliography %%%    
%% Harvard
\bibliographystyle{model2-names.bst}\biboptions{authoryear}
    \nocite{Galbraith1952}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{AAA}
    
\author{ZZZ}


\begin{abstract}
    Abstract text
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
keyword1 \sep keyword2
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}

\linenumbers

Hello


\bibliography{contents/references}

\end{document}
```

The bib entry for `Galbraith1952` would be:

```
@book{Galbraith1952,
address = {Cambridge, MA},
author = {Galbraith, John Kenneth},
publisher = {Harvard University Press},
title = {A Theory of Price Control},
year = {1952}
}
```

The final pdf does not include `Galbraith1952`.

For reference on `elsearticle.cls`, please see this [link](https://www.elsevier.com/authors/author-schemas/latex-instructions).  It can be downloaded from [here](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/elsarticle).

Comment: The issue is *not* related to the `elsarticle` document class. It's caused by placing the intruction `\nocite{Galbraith1952}` in the preamble, i.e., before `\begin{document}`. Move the instruction into the body of the document and you'll be fine.

Comment: With normal BibTeX `\nocite` needs to be placed in the document body. (If you use `biblatex` it is allowed in the preamble.) This restriction may possibly be lifted soon-ish (https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/424).

Comment: Note that the style name in `\bibliographystyle` should be given without the file extension. So `\bibliographystyle{model2-names.bst}` should be `\bibliographystyle{model2-names}`. (I guess most systems nowadays still compile fine if you erroneously include the file extension, but it is still a good idea to stick to the intended syntax.)

Comment: @moewe Yes it still does compile even with the file extension. And thank you for the clarification regarding the `biblatex`.  I have another document using `biblatex` and I had put the `\nocite` in the preamble, and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @Mico It works ok now. Thank you.